# Writing to multiple files with cat

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a some empty html files that i want to write. I am trying this

```
cat account_settings/account_settings.html >> assets/assets.html, users/users.html
```

to attempt to write to the files `assets.html` and `users.html`.

How can I write to multiple files?

Comment: In zsh, `cat foo > a > b` works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `tee` command

```
NAME
       tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
```

e.g.

```
cat account_settings/account_settings.html | tee -a assets/assets.html users/users.html
```

or (using input redirection)

```
tee -a assets/assets.html users/users.html < account_settings/account_settings.html
```

As noted in the manual page, `tee` also outputs the contents to the terminal (standard output) - if you don't want to see that, redirect stdout to null

```
tee -a assets/assets.html users/users.html < account_settings/account_settings.html > /dev/null
```

Comment: Can tee -a also be used when deleting contents  `truncate -s 0 tee -a assets/assets.html users/users.html`

Comment: @LeQs Are you trying to erase the files before writing to them?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Its just a random thought that came to mind unrelated to my original question.

Comment: @LeQs truncating and appending seem incompatible - what exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to truncate multiple files, you can simply give multiple filename arguments to the truncate command e.g. `truncate -s0 foo bar baz`. You *could* do something like `: | tee foo bar baz` I guess.

Comment: @steeldriver I am inside a folder `templates`. Inside the folder `templates` i have folders users and credit.  I want to truncate files `users/users.html` and `credit/credit.html` while inside templates folder, that's what i am trying to do.

Comment: @LeQs does `truncate -s0 users/users.html credit/credit.html` not do what you want in that case?

Answer (score 6):

Just for-loop over the list of files you want

```
for file in assets/assets.html users/users.html
do
    cat account_settings/account_settings.html >> "$file"
done
```